# Use the well ordering principle to show that each nonempty set S consisting of negative integers has a largest element.

Tags: real-analysis

I have question

> **Q**
>   Use the well ordering principle to show that each nonempty set S consisting of negative integers has a largest element.

I hope someone can answer

Thanks
please explain more not clear this answer

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $T$ be the set of all numbers $-s$, where $s$ ranges over $S$. Then $T$ is a non-empty set of positive integers, so has a smallest element.

Note that $x\le y$ if and only if $-y\le -x$.